# Extract part of xml file with python etree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have big xml file that looks as one below. I have put just part of it, as it is >2gb, so just that you see the structure. Basicly all `SubNetwork parents` have same structure as the one I showed below. What I want to do is to extract only part of this xml file with the `<ManagedElementId string="xxxx" />` (where xxx i the input variable). Here is my code and xml:

```
<Create> 
<SubNetwork networkType="GSM" userLabel="BSC">
.
.
</SubNetwork>
<SubNetwork networkType="WCDMA" userLabel="RNC01">
.
.
</SubNetwork>
<SubNetwork networkType="IPRAN" userLabel="IPRAN">
.
.
</SubNetwork>
<SubNetwork networkType="WCDMA" userLabel="RNC02">
                  <ManagedElement sourceType="CELLO">
                     <ManagedElementId string="3GALPAS" />
                     <primaryType type="RBS" />
                   .
                   .
                  </ManagedElement>
                  <ManagedElement sourceType="CELLO">
                     <ManagedElementId string="3GTUTI" />
                     <primaryType type="RBS" />
                   .
                   .
                  </ManagedElement>
                    <ManagedElement sourceType="CELLO">
                     <ManagedElementId string="3GHHH" />
                     <primaryType type="RBS" />
                   .
                   .
                  </ManagedElement>
</SubNetwork>
</Create>
```

and the code

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring, tostring
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
from xml.etree.ElementTree import SubElement
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment


with open(r"C:\\Users\\etihkru\\Desktop\\h4.xml", 'rt') as f:
   root = ET.parse(f)
   tree=root.getroot()
   with open(r"C:\\Users\\etihkru\\Desktop\\list_of_xxx", 'r') as f2:
        for line in f2:
             line=line.rstrip()
             line1='"' + line + '"'
             xp_str1 = str(('.//ManagedElementId[@string='))
             xp_str2 = str("]/../../")
             str_elem = xp_str1 + line1 + xp_str2 
             for item in tree.findall(str_elem):
                    print ET.tostring(item)
```

and file `list_of_xxx` is as below:

```
3GALPAS
3GTUTI
```

As said there is numerues number of  `<ManagedElementId string=/>`, and I just want to extract the ones that are in `list_of_xxx`.

So I want output as below:

```
<SubNetwork networkType="WCDMA" userLabel="RNC02">
                  <ManagedElement sourceType="CELLO">
                     <ManagedElementId string="3GALPAS" />
                     <primaryType type="RBS" />
                   .
                   .
                  </ManagedElement>
</SubNetwork>
<SubNetwork networkType="WCDMA" userLabel="RNC02">
                  <ManagedElement sourceType="CELLO">
                     <ManagedElementId string="3GTUTI" />
                     <primaryType type="RBS" />
                   .
                   .
                  </ManagedElement>
</SubNetwork>
```

So, I want to find all `ManagedElementIds` as given in list_of_xxx,and their parents `ManagedElement` and `SubNetwork`, and write them as given above. Every `MangedElementid` should be closed with parents as mentioned. I'm uing python 2.6 without lxml, as I don't have right to install it.

Comment: What's not working about the sample code you posted?

Comment: well, I don't get parents, Subnetwork and ManagedElement, and I want this in my output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting *part* of XML in the sense that that *part* exists in the source XML should be trivial. For example, getting `ManagedElement`s containing certain `ManagedElementId` that you're interested in will be easy. But here you seems want them wrapped within `SubNetwork` parent node.

In the source XML, `SubNetwork` contains mix of elements you want to get and other elements you want to strip from the result, so there is actually no such `SubNetwork` containing *only* `ManagedElement` nodes you want.

We can approach this by extracting `ManagedElement` nodes from the source XML, and add them to a reconstructed parent `SubNetwork` node :

```
.....
.....
for line in f2:
    line = line.rstrip()
    #get all subnet nodes containing certain ManagedElementId
    subnet_path = ".//ManagedElementId[@string='{0}']/../.."
    subnet_path = subnet_path.format(line)
    for subnet in tree.findall(subnet_path):
        #reconstruct subnet node:
        parent = ET.Element(subnet.tag, attrib=subnet.attrib)
        #path to find all ManagedElement containing certain ManagedElementId
        content_path = ".//ManagedElementId[@string='{0}']/..".format(line)
        #append all ManagedElement found to the new subnet:
        for content in subnet.findall(content_path):
            parent.append(content)
        #print new subnet:
        print ET.tostring(parent)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working great. I just replaced ET.create, with ET.Element.

Comment: my bad, that was a copy-paste error when I tried to modify my working code to comply with your existing code. Fixed that

Comment: I had to ask new question, as on python 2.6 it's not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000251/python-2-6-etree-not-working